# How to modify axis labels within ggplot labs()

Tags: r, ggplot2, stringr

Say I want to modify a ggplot axis label with the str_to_title() function.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    labs(x = ~str_to_title(.x))
```

Rather than my x-axis being labeled 'Wt' it will be labeled 'str_to_title(.x)'. Is there a way to apply functions within the labs() function?

Answer (score 2):

`labs` doesn't do programmatic NSE like many other components of `ggplot2`. One option is to define the columns programmatically, use `aes_` and `as.name` (or [other ways too](https://ggplot2-book.org/programming.html#indirectly-referring-to-variables)) and it'll work.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr) # str_to_title
xx <- "wt"; yy <- "mpg"
ggplot(mtcars, aes_(x = as.name(xx), y = as.name(yy))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(x = str_to_title(xx))
```

[image: ggplot with "dynamic" x-label]